# NetCDF to raster layer, spacing in their coordinate values

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, netcdf

I'm trying to convert a NetCDF file to a raster layer in ArcGIS Pro, in order to make a space-time animation.
But I'm getting a error message that I don't know how to solve:

```
ERROR 000276: One or both dimensions have variable spacing in their coordinate values
```

I know that the spacing between x-coordinates must be equal and the spacing between y-coordinates must be equal, but the differences between latitudes decreases towards poles, so, how can I correct this?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy


# Set local variables
inNetCDFFile = "C:/Users/Miguel/Documents/ORIGINS/animationWRF/data/wrfout/wrfout_d03_2020-03- 
09_00_00_00.nc"
variable = "CO2_ANT"
XDimension = "XLON"
YDimension = "YLAT"
outRasterLayer = "C:/Users/Miguel/Documents/ORIGINS/animationWRF/data/netcdf2raster/wrfout_d03_2020- 
03-09_00_00_00"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension,
                           outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, 
                           valueSelectionMethod)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you were able to find out the fix for this.

I recently faced this concern with a dataset received from an Ocean researcher.

The shared NetCDF files were displaying variable spacing wrt to latitude.

**As a workaround:**

Create a feature layer first using the "[Make NetCDF Feature Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/multidimension/make-netcdf-feature-layer.htm) " Geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro, and then rasterize the created output. Specify latitude and longitude as Row Dimensions as well. Without row dimensions, the tool creates one point only using the 1st value of latitude and the 1st value of longitude.

[image]